# Python: How to use BeautifulSoup to deal with encoding issues?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my first time using BeautifulSoup.

Basically, I use BeautifulSoup to extract data. I am trying to construct a table in csv based on the webtable. And an example row of my table looks like this:

```
[<td>1</td>, <td> Chief executives and senior officials</td>, <td>£120,830</td>,<td>-3.8</td>]
```

Now, the problem is when I use `.text.encode('utf8')`, the output becomes:

```
('1', ' Chief executives and senior officials', '\xc2\xa3120,830', '-3.8')
```

The figure `£120,830` becomes `\xc2\xa3120,830`, which I have no idea what kind of encoding this is. Is there a way that I can get the proper output `£120,830` rather than the crazy encoding ?

Alternatively, is there a way to make this crazy encoded thing `\xc2\xa3120,830` to look like `£120,830` in my csv ? Does anyone know how to deal with these kind of problem ?

Another alternative is to remove the `<td>` tags and keep the content, but how can I do that in python ? Is there an efficient way of getting rid of these tags ? 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how £ comes out when you encode it as UTF-8. If that's not what you want, why are you encoding it?

In more detail, UTF-8 encodes [U+00A3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm) as the byte sequence 0xC2 0xA3 (two bytes) which Python displays in a string as `'\xc2\xa3'`.

If you do want this in a file and you want the file to be UTF-8 encoded, nothing is wrong, except maybe what you are using to look at the file.